# How make an UPDATE/INSERT query on Linked Server?

Tags: sql, sql-update, linked-server

I have a linked server to which I have to update data or insert new data coming from my DB.
So, I have to define a query in SQL in order to do that
I already search on the net, but any solution I found work.
Can somebody help me??

Suppose that the name of my linkedServer is AAA and the table of linked server that I have to update is BBB, I tried with

```
UPDATE AAA.BBB AS I
SET
   I.X = @MYVALUEX
   I.Y = @MYVALUEY
WHERE
  ...
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions,

Deborah

Comment: Anytime you query a linked server you need to use the 4-partname (Server, database, schema, tablename). You also need to ensure a linked server is actually set-up.

Comment: The linked server is set-up. I check the RPC and RPC-Out properties and they are set to True. I don't understand why, using a select with the openquery function, everything goes right, but when I define the update query, it tell me that I'm using an Invalid object name. The DB linked throught linked server (and in which i Want apply changes) is an Oracle DB, while I'm working with SQL. May this could be the problem??

Answer (score 3):

I solve my problem using the EXEC command:

```
exec('update BBB
     set X = ''aaaaaa''
     WHERE Y = ''bbbbbb''') AT [AAA]
```

what do you think about this solution?

Comment: For this to work, one needs to make sure that the RPC and RPC Out options are set to True in Linked Server's properties (Server Options page)

Answer (score 2):

```
update [linked-server].dbname.dbo.tablename
...
where
...
```

Don't change the `dbo`.

Comment: I tried to use your suggestion, but it doesn't work! I get the follow error: "Invalid use of schema or catalog for OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "AAA". A four-part name was supplied, but the provider does not expose the necessary interfaces to use a catalog or schema." How can I solve??

Answer (score 0):

delete the "AS" part, 'as' can be used in select statement, not in update, it's an alias, there's no reason to give one since you don't have a resultset, also change I.X to X and I.Y to Y